# Translate animation through Bitmap like Goibibo Application

Tags: android, animation, bitmap, android-canvas, surfaceview

I am doing animation, some translate animation  using but this not what I want I have given the reference of an app Front screen with animation...having three bubbles .initially they will be all together and after onTouch() it just opens up translating to its x,y coordinates

This is the class i am using to translate but i know lots of work has to be done

My Draw view class-

```
public class DrawView extends View {
Paint paint = new Paint();
private int height;
Bitmap circlegreen ,circlered,circleyellow;

    public DrawView(Context context, int height) {
        super(context); 
        this.height = height;

        circlegreen=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.circlegreen);
        circlered=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.circlered);
        circleyellow=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.circleyellow);
        this.height= this.height+circleyellow.getHeight();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    paint.setColor(Color.RED);
          canvas.drawBitmap(circlegreen, 30, height, paint);
          canvas.drawBitmap(circlered, 30, height, paint);
          canvas.drawBitmap(circleyellow, 30, height, paint);
       // canvas.drawRect(30, height, 60, 300, paint );

    }

And in the fragment i am adding this DrawView to container..


        @SuppressLint("NewApi")
        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, final ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            //View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
            //dineInBtn=(Button) view.findViewById(R.id.dinein);
            Display display = getActivity().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
            Point size = new Point();
            display.getSize(size);
            int width = size.x;
             height = size.y;

             Log.v("width=", width+"");
             Log.v("height=", height+"");

            final CountDownTimer timer = new CountDownTimer(2000, 50) {

                @Override
                public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

                    height = height - 10;
                    drawView = new DrawView(getActivity(), height);
                    drawView.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
                    container.addView(drawView);
                }

                @Override
                public void onFinish() {

                }
            };
            Runnable run=new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    timer.start();

                }
            };
            new Thread(run).start();
```

Also attaching the image..[image]

Answer (score 1):

Can use arc menu library :
[here is library](http://www.androidviews.net/2012/12/arcmenu/)

Answer (score -1):

Its ARC Menu Library you can find the sample example below 
https://github.com/daCapricorn/ArcMenu